# Best approach to enrich User model in Django pluggable app

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I am currently working on expanding `https://github.com/suutari/drf-jwt-2fa`, which provides two-factor authentication over jwt for rest-framework.

I would like to make the two-factor auth non-enforced; that is, users should be able to choose if they want this extra security.
For that purpose, I would like to add a boolean field (lets call it two_auth) to the user model.

What is the best approach to add this field?

I am currently thinking on some possibilities, but none of them seems to be neat enough:

- *Create a relation table (user_id, two_auth) without foreign-key enforcement*: I should use signals for user deletion
- *Create a relation table (user_id, two_auth) with foreign-key enforcement*: The foreign key should point to the model specified at settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL. I generally like model declaration parameters to be explicit, not patchable.

Answer (score 0):

This is a nice [guide](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/07/22/how-to-extend-django-user-model.html) on options to extend the built-in user model.